# PowerBi: incremental data load by using OData feed

Tags: powerbi

is there any possibility to save previous data before overriding because of refreshing data?

**Steps i have done:**

- I Created a table and appended to table A
- Created a Column called DateTime with the function
  DateTime.LocalNow()

Now i have a problem how to save previous data before the refreshing phase. I need to preserve the timestamp of previous data and actually data.

**Example giving:**

Before refreshing:

Table A:
|Columnname x| DateTime             | ....
| value |   23.03.2016 23:00

New Table:
|Columnname x| DateTime         | ....
| value     | 23.03.2016 23:00

After refreshing:

Table A:
|Columnname x| DateTime | ....
| value | 23.03.2016 23:00
| value 2   | 23.03.2016 23:01

New Table:
|Columnname x| DateTime | ....
| value     | 23.03.2016 23:00
| value 2   | 23.03.2016 23:01

kind regards

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do the examples show? What you have now or what you want to see?

Comment: heading of your question is incremental data load, and description shows that you want to stored multiple versions of a your data. Further in your example after refreshing both Table A and New Table has same values, this is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incremental refreshes in the Power BI Service or Power BI Desktop aren't currently supported. But please vote for this [feature](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7288623-power-query-incremental-data-loads). (*update: see that link for info on a preview feature that does this*)

If you need this behavior you need to load these rows to a database then incrementally load the database. The load to Power BI will still be a full load of the table(s).

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

This is now available in PowerBI Premium

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-incremental-refresh)

Incremental refresh enables very large datasets in the Power BI Premium service with the following benefits:

- Refreshes are faster. Only data that has changed needs to be refreshed. For example, refresh only the last 5 days of a 10-year dataset.
- Refreshes are more reliable. For example, it is not necessary to maintain long-running connections to volatile source systems.
- Resource consumption is reduced. Less data to refresh reduces overall consumption of memory and other resources.